# JPA findByFieldNameIn returning same object(last record) multiple times

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, impala

Use case-

```
    List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("1","2");
        
        List<Entity> list = repo.findByOrderNumberIn(ids);
        for(Entity model: list) {
            System.out.println(model.toString());
        }
```

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Serializable> {

    List<Entity> findByOrderNumberIn(List<String> ids);
```

Expected output -

```
 Entity[1]
 Entity[2]
```

actually result getting

```
 Entity[2]
 Entity[2]
```

not sure whether Entity 1 is overriding.

Comment: There is lack of info.please add code with Entity class and what is in db

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.